# postgresql string extraction

Tags: string, postgresql

I have some strings like:

```
   1.  '"first" and "second"'
   2.  '"first" and "second" or "third"'
```

I need to extract words from these strings and translate the string as below:

```
1. '%first%' and '%second%'

2. 
    '%first%' and '%second%' 
    '%first%' and '%third%'
```

I'm using Postgresql 5.9.2. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I hope you meant Postgres 9.5.2

Comment: Are these structures ('a' AND 'b') and ('a' AND 'b' OR 'c') the two only ones are can they be more general? (Do you want to get a boolean parser?)

Comment: yeah it's 9.5.2 :) and again yes, it's the more common structure. I have no idea about boolean parser!